# boost zip iterator for two different list size

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have used boost zip iterator for same size list, accidentally i have passed different size list to iterate. Can we use boost zip iterator for two different size, if not then any other choice in boost or c++?

Comment: What should the behaviour of such an iterator be if it encounters an end() in one of the sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp) we can determine the following facts.

1. Comparison:

> Two zip iterators are equal if all iterators in the iterator tuple are equal.

2. Advancing:

> Advancing a zip iterator means to advance all iterators in the iterator tuple.

3. Dereferencing:

> Dereferencing returns a tuple built from the dereferenced iterators in the iterator tuple.

---

When you iterate (having your as your end condition comparison against something like `boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(end1, end2))`) and reach and of one of the lists, the loop will not terminate (see 1), leading to invalid dereference (see 3).

---

You should find the common length of the two lists (e.g. `std::min(list1.size(), list2.size()`) and initialize the end iterator so that both ranges are of equal length.

Comment: You could also use [`boost::adaptors::sliced`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html) to constrain your combined range to the minimal size.